# Maximize a function with a condition.

Tags: numerical-optimization

> The problem is placing $n$ number of points on a sphere in
>   $\mathbb{R}^m$, as far apart as possible from eachother. I want to
>   formulate this problem as an optimizationproblem where the
>   objectfunction is the function that describes the sum of all distances
>   between the points and the condition is for the point to actually be
>   *on* the sphere.

So I need to set upp the problem as searching for $\text{max} \ f(n)$ when $g(n)=0.$

Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ be the set of points placed on the sphere and $p_i=(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)$. First, we have that

$$f(n) = \sum_{i<j}|p_i-p_j|.$$

For the points to be on the hypersphere with radius $r$, they have to be on the same distance from the origin, so

$$g(n)=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2=r^2.$$

Are my functions correct? Note that this function is to be maximized using MATLAB, but I first need to set up the correct equations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be correct to me.

As an alternative for the distance you could also consider the following $$f(n) = \sum_{i<j}(p_i-p_j)\cdot (p_i-p_j)$$

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't get is how any of them are dependant on $n$, when there is no $n$ in the RHS?

Comment: @Parseval If you are going to solve with Matlab then I guess that the solution is numerical, then you need to fix n at a certain value and then try to extrapolate a general result.

Comment: Yes, but if $n$ is then fixed, how do I denote the variable?

Comment: @Parseval It depends by the commands you are using with Matlab, it doesn't seem a problem of set up. I guess there is a function to define with n as parameter.

Comment: But I can just put $n=25$ for example, but then I need something that is varying. I feel like my functions are not correct, something is missing. As they are now, they feel impossible to maximize.

Comment: I think you shoul put different values of n to get different solutions, plot it and try to figure out a general pattern. For my knowledge with matlab we can only obtain numerical solutions then you need to fix n.

Comment: But even if I do it for many different values of $n$, I don't have any variable like $x$ in a function $f(x)$. All the examples on youtube use functions like $f(x,y) = 2\sin(x)+3xy+\cos(y)$ and then maximize this. I can't do this with my functons.